# Queryselector giving null value for div class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a simple code to select HTML div class and apply event listener on it. But my query selector gives a null value in the console. I tried several times but can't get a clear reason for it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .grandparent
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 60vh;
            width: 60vh;
            background-color: red;
            margin-top: 10%;
        
        }

        .parent
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 40vh;
            width: 40vh;
            background-color: blue;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .child
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 25vh;
            width: 25vh;
            background-color: green;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        const grandparent = document.querySelector('.grandparent');
        const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
        const child = document.querySelector('.child');
        console.log(parent);

        /*
        grandparent.addEventListener('click', e=> {
            console.log(e);
        });*/
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grandparent">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've written a simple code to select HTML div class and apply event listener on it. But my query selector gives a null value in the console. I tried several times but can't get a clear reason for it.

Comment: You are running the JS before the elements have been loaded.

Comment: Just like @AHaworth mentioned the JS is run before the HTML elements have loaded. The simplest solution would be to add 'defer' to your script tag like this: <script defer> </script>

Comment: @Niels Thanks for this information.